# how to add two tables in one model class (Room) android studio

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room

The problem is: I am getting news from API and cache them in an entity(articles_table) with (Articles class), so I want to add another entity(bookmark_table) with the same (Articles) model class.

I want inside Articles model class:

- First articles_table (this will represent the home cache news)
- second articles_bookmark_table (this will represent user bookmarks)

is this possible? to have two tables in one class? or there is another way that does the same thing?

```
     @Entity(tableName = "articles_table")
        data class Articles(
            @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
            val id: Int,
            val author: String,
            val date: String,
            val img: String,
            val source: String,
            val title: String,
            val url: String,
            val interest:String
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

> is this possible? to have two tables in one class?

No, an `@Entity` defines a class as a table as per

> Marks a class as an entity. This class will have a mapping SQLite table in the database. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Entity

You could embed the Article Class into another @Entity class and have what is effectively a second, nearly identically structured, table.
e.g. :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "articles_bookmark_table", primaryKeys = ["id"])
data class BookMarkArticles(
    @Embedded
    val articles: Articles
)
```

- note that when Embedding the Primary Key is not included, hence the need to  define it.
- I would suggest that this is a precarious way to go as it may result in confusion over ambiguous columns as the column names would be identical.

However, I'd suggest that rather than 2 basically identical tables, that you simply add an indicator (Boolean) that determines whether or not it is a bookmark row or not. e.g. :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "articles_table")
data class Articles(
    @PrimaryKey //<<<<<<<<<< autoGenerate removed
    val id: Int? = null, //<<<<<<<<<< defaults to null so if not provided auto generates id
    val author: String,
    val date: String,
    val img: String,
    val source: String,
    val title: String,
    val url: String,
    val interest:String,
    val bookmark:Boolean //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED to distinguish bookmark row or not
)
```

using the 2 tables with the embedded introduces a nuance when inserting/extracting, as the following demo.

The demo uses slightly modified Articles and BookMarkArticles and the 2nd Articles as ArticlesV2 to show both ways together.

So **Articles** is :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "articles_table")
data class Articles(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int? = null,
    val author: String,
    val date: String,
    val img: String,
    val source: String,
    val title: String,
    val url: String,
    val interest:String
)
```

-i.e. id is allowed to be null and thus when not provided the id will be automatically generated.

**BookMarkArticles** (Embeds Articles) is :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "articles_bookmark_table", primaryKeys = ["id"])
data class BookMarkArticles(
    @Embedded
    val articles: Articles
)
```

**ArticlesV2** (the two types in a single table) is :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "articles_v2_table")
data class ArticlesV2(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int? = null,
    val author: String,
    val date: String,
    val img: String,
    val source: String,
    val title: String,
    val url: String,
    val interest:String,
    val bookmark:Boolean
)
```

**Dao**'s are :-

```
@Insert
abstract fun insert(articles: Articles): Long
@Insert
abstract fun insert(bookMarkArticles: BookMarkArticles): Long
@Insert
abstract fun insert(articlesV2: ArticlesV2): Long

@Query("SELECT * FROM articles_table")
abstract fun getAllArticles(): List<Articles>
@Query("SELECT * FROM articles_bookmark_table")
abstract fun getAllBookmarkedArticles(): List<BookMarkArticles>
@Query("SELECT * FROM articles_v2_table WHERE bookmark=:bookmarked")
abstract fun getAllArticleV2s(bookmarked: Boolean): List<ArticlesV2>
```

In an Activity is the following code :-

```
    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
    dao = db.getDao()

    dao.insert(Articles(author = "Fred",date = "2021-01-01",img = "MyImage", title = "MyTitle", url = "MyUrl",source = "MySource",interest = "MyInterest"))
    dao.insert(Articles(author = "Bert",date = "2021-01-01",img = "MyImage", title = "MyTitle", url = "MyUrl",source = "MySource",interest = "MyInterest"))
    dao.insert(BookMarkArticles(Articles(author = "Fred",date = "2021-01-01",img = "MyImage", title = "MyTitle", url = "MyUrl",source = "MySource",interest = "MyInterest")))
    dao.insert(BookMarkArticles(Articles(author = "Bert",date = "2021-01-01",img = "MyImage", title = "MyTitle", url = "MyUrl",source = "MySource",interest = "MyInterest")))
    dao.insert(ArticlesV2(author = "Fred",date = "2021-01-01",img = "MyImage", title = "MyTitle", url = "MyUrl",source = "MySource",interest = "MyInterest",bookmark = false))
    dao.insert(ArticlesV2(author = "Bert",date = "2021-01-01",img = "MyImage", title = "MyTitle", url = "MyUrl",source = "MySource",interest = "MyInterest",bookmark = false))
    dao.insert(ArticlesV2(author = "Fred",date = "2021-01-01",img = "MyImage", title = "MyTitle", url = "MyUrl",source = "MySource",interest = "MyInterest",bookmark = true))
    dao.insert(ArticlesV2(author = "Bert",date = "2021-01-01",img = "MyImage", title = "MyTitle", url = "MyUrl",source = "MySource",interest = "MyInterest",bookmark = true))

    for(a: Articles in dao.getAllArticles()) {
        Log.d("ARTICLEINFO","(not bookmark) Author is ${a.author} ID is ${a.id} etc")
    }
    for(b: BookMarkArticles in dao.getAllBookmarkedArticles()) {
        Log.d("ARTICLEINFO","(bookmark) Author is ${b.articles.author} ID is ${b.articles.id} etc")
    }
    for(a: ArticlesV2 in dao.getAllArticleV2s(false)) {
        Log.d("ARTICLEV2INFO","(not bookmark) Author is ${a.author} ID is ${a.id} etc BOOKMARK Flag is ${a.bookmark}")
    }
    for(a: ArticlesV2 in dao.getAllArticleV2s(true)) {
        Log.d("ARTICLEV2INFO","(bookmark) Author is ${a.author} ID is ${a.id} etc BOOKMARK Flag is ${a.bookmark}")
    }
```

- Note the nuance (nusiance) that a BookMarkArticles is constructed via an Articles object and that when extracting a BookMarkArticles that it has an embedded Articles object.

The **result** in the log :-

```
2021-09-01 16:32:09.844 D/ARTICLEINFO: (not bookmark) Author is Fred ID is 1 etc
2021-09-01 16:32:09.845 D/ARTICLEINFO: (not bookmark) Author is Bert ID is 2 etc


2021-09-01 16:32:09.847 D/ARTICLEINFO: (bookmark) Author is Fred ID is 1 etc
2021-09-01 16:32:09.847 D/ARTICLEINFO: (bookmark) Author is Bert ID is 2 etc


2021-09-01 16:32:09.849 D/ARTICLEV2INFO: (not bookmark) Author is Fred ID is 1 etc BOOKMARK Flag is false
2021-09-01 16:32:09.849 D/ARTICLEV2INFO: (not bookmark) Author is Bert ID is 2 etc BOOKMARK Flag is false
2021-09-01 16:32:09.851 D/ARTICLEV2INFO: (bookmark) Author is Fred ID is 3 etc BOOKMARK Flag is true
2021-09-01 16:32:09.851 D/ARTICLEV2INFO: (bookmark) Author is Bert ID is 4 etc BOOKMARK Flag is true
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort! but I tried another solution and it worked fine for me and It's more suitable for my project.